# Why is this monit config reminder syntax not resulting in repeated alerts?

Tags: monit

I have setup a monit config to check that a jenkins build node is connected (its VPN connection is still up) by checking for its VPN IP address on a server that is inside the network already. It seems to work at least once when the computer is not connected. But it only seems to trigger once in a blue moon and not repeatedly like I want it to.

```
check host JenkinsMacOSXNode with address 192.168.237.10
if failed icmp type echo
  count 5 with timeout 5 seconds
  2 times within 3 cycles
then alert with reminder on 3 cycles
alert admin@ourdomain.com
```

Is the above syntax correct for having an alert sent repeatedly when an expected computer is not pingable?

In case the next question is how often is the cycle set to, the `/etc/monit/monitrc` indicates `set daemon 120` so each cycle should be every 2 minutes

Is there a better way to accomplish checking for a computer that should be connected via VPN to the network and alert if it is not?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the alert with reminder definition  before the test:

```
set alert admin@ourdomain.com with reminder on 3 cycles
check host JenkinsMacOSXNode with address 192.168.237.10
if failed icmp type echo
  count 5 with timeout 5 seconds
  2 times within 3 cycles
then alert
```